# iterator (array.each) as return value of method in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this class :

```
class MyArray
  attr_accessor :data

  def initialize(my_object = nil)
    @data = Array[*my_object]
  end

  def <<(y)
    @data << y
  end

  def each
    @data.each
  end
end
```

And I am using it like this

> ```
> subject = MyArray.new([2, 5, 3])
>   d = []   
>   subject.each { |i|
>     d << i
>   }
> ```

The problem is, that it does not iterate even once through the -subject.each-. What should I do to return the "each" value from array as method return value? How to return the iterator itself?

I tried this and it is not working too :

> ```
>   def each
>     [2,5,3].each
>   end
> ```

---

Thanks to "meagar" and "Erik Allik" we have the right answer : (only the "def each" method has changed)

```
class MyArray
  attr_accessor :data

  def initialize(my_object = nil)
    @data = Array[*my_object]
  end

  def <<(y)
    @data << y
  end

  def each(&block)
    @data.each(&block)
  end
end
```

Comment: You should edit your question to include your `initialize` method.  You may think it should be obvious that you have a correct constructor, but there are many similiar questions at SO in which the poster's problem lies in off-screen code (or in the absence thereof), especially when the poster is new to Ruby.

Comment: Good point, I edited it

Comment: Note that you could replace your constructor with `def initialize(my_object = nil) @data = Array[*my_object] end`.  This way, `my_object` can be any collection other than a set (array, hash, range), a string, a proc or an immutable object (integer, float, true, false, nil).  Others? Glasses up for the mighty splat!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `each {block}` is actually invoking `each` on the array and *passing in a block* argument to the method. Your block argument is being ignored.

If you want this to work, you need to forward the block into your nested `each` call:

```
class Test
  def each(&block)
     [1, 2, 3].each(&block)
  end
end

Test.new.each do |i|
  puts i
end
```

If you want to return an iterator, you're free to do so, but you have to invoke `each` *on that iterator*, and give *it* the block:

```
class Test
  def each
    [1, 2, 3].each
  end
end

Test.new.each.each do |i|
   puts i
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the block passed to your custom `def each` on to the actual underlyign `each`:

```
def each(&block)  # take the block passed to each as a Proc object
    @data.each(&block)  # pass the Proc on as a block to the underlying each
end
```

which is equivalent to:

```
def each
    # just create a new block that calls the passed in block
    # without creating an intermediate Proc object
    @data.each { |i| yield i }
end
```

Comment: Thanks too, this answer is almost the same as the one before and you are right :).